# Bean Property dataSource Not Writable in Spring + Hibernate 3

Tags: java

I have searched a lot of places, but have not found a solution to the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDaoImpl' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.springhibernate.example.HibernateDaoImpl]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1385)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.springhibernate.example.SpringHibernateDemo.main(SpringHibernateDemo.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.springhibernate.example.HibernateDaoImpl]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1382)
    ... 13 more
```

The Exception is from the following spring xml file config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.springhibernate.example"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HibernateTest"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="admin"/>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateDaoImpl" class="com.springhibernate.example.HibernateDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springhibernate.model"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </prop>
    </props>
    </property>

</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Let's see com.springhibernate.example.HibernateDaoImpl, it says 'Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable...'

Answer (score 0):

Haven't heard back from you yet - but I'm going to go out on a limb here

Typically, for a Hibernate DAO object, you want the sessionFactory and not the dataSource.  So give your DAO a way to set the sessionFactory (e.g. a setter or a constructor - I prefer constructor as it doesn't need to be mutable).

```
public class HibernateDaoImpl implements HibernateDao
{
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   public HibernateDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
   {
     this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
   }
}
```

Config

```
 <bean id="hibernateDaoImpl" class="com.springhibernate.example.HibernateDaoImpl">
   <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory"/>
 </bean>
```

Comment: let me post it in parts, Its not going all at once. 1st part is below: